# API success response not showing up in flutter emulator

Tags: flutter, android-emulator

I am new to flutter and am working on login and register authentication with API. But When ever I get a success response from the API regarding the registration, it is not showing up in the emulator, but I do get the success message in the flutter terminal. It is only happening for success messages. For error message I do get the output message in emulator. can someone please help.

success message in flutter terminal is :

The Flutter DevTools debugger and profiler on Android SDK built for x86 is available at:
I/flutter ( 6786): {status: true, message: User registered succesfully., seedPhase: web wheel danger raise country lunch glory then humble cherry animal fever}

```
Register(String email, userid, pass, confpass) async {
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
Map data = {
  'email': email,
  'userId': userid,
  'password': pass,
  'confirmPassword': confpass
};
var jsonResponse = null;
var response = await http.post(Uri.parse("http://10.0.2.2:8000/register"), body: data);
if(response.statusCode == 201) {
  jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body);
  print(jsonResponse);
  if(jsonResponse != null) {
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = false;
    });
    succMsg = response.body;
    print("successfuly: ${response.body}");
    sharedPreferences.setString("token", jsonResponse['token']);
    //ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text("successfully registered")));
    //Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => MainPage()), (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
  }
}
else {
  setState(() {
    _isLoading = false;
  });
  errorMsg = response.body;
  print("The error message is: ${response.body}");
}
```

}

Comment: Image of the code snippet doesn't appear.

Comment: sorry. It seems I am yet not allowed to upload image

Comment: added the snippet code

Comment: can someone please help me out with this?

Comment: confirm response is 201.

Comment: yes the response is 201

Comment: Can you add a sample of success and failure response code. So that we can know what's happening.

Comment: added the success message from flutter terminal. but the same message is not getting displayed in the emulator. I was actually being denied uploading ant images, so have pasted the response I get from the flutter terminal

Comment: The Flutter DevTools debugger and profiler on Android SDK built for x86 is available at:
I/flutter ( 6786): {status: true, message: User registered succesfully., seedPhase: web wheel danger raise country lunch glory then humble cherry animal fever}